# How to import puppeteer-tab-recorder in electron preload

Tags: javascript, electron, puppeteer, video-recording

I am new to javascript and electron. I created a small project which is about recording multiple puppeteer tabs at the same time so I used this package called [puppeteer-tab-recorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-tab-recorder). I want to use this package to record some tabs with video and audio but there is something wrong with the way to import this package. This is how I imported it:

```
const {
  recommandChromeArgs,
  createTabRecorder,
} = require("puppeteer-tab-recorder");
```

but it throws this error:

```
VM157 renderer_init:2 Error: require() of ES Module D:\...\node_modules\puppeteer-tab-recorder\dist\index.js from D:\...\scripts\preload.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in D:\...\scripts\preload.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

I tried asking AI for help but I didn't understand anything so if someone can tell me what am I doing wrong I would appreciate it.